# Can I store sha256 hashed passwords in plain text?

Tags: php, security, passwords, sha256, password-hash

So I have php code which saves a hashed version of a password to a file called passwords.txt. As it currently stands, anyone who knows the directory of the file (www.example.com/datacache/passwords.txt) can access it. Is this the incorrect way of doing it? I thought I followed the guide to correct password treatment to the letter, but this seems oddly insecure. Thoughts? Suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: [Don't use SHA256 for passwords](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are two questions here:

**1) Is it ok to store the hashes in a file**

Saving passwords in a file is not better or worse than storing it in a database. The point with a file is, that it should be stored outside of the WWW root directory. Most providers offer a private directory, which can be accessed by code, but canot be reached for HTTP requests.

**2) Is it safe to use SHA-256 for hashing passwords**

No SHA-* and MD5 should not be used directly to hash passwords, because they are too fast and therefore can be brute-forced too easily. Instead one should use a slow function like BCrypt, [PBKDF2](https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing) or [SCrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#php-scrypt), they offer a cost factor and add a safe salt automatically.

PHP offers [a password API](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) with two functions [password_hash()](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) and [password_verify()](https://secure.php.net/password_verify). Use them, they are future proof and will produce BCrypt hashes.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

If you're running an old version of PHP that doesn't have this API, upgrade. If for some reason you can't, check out [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Is there a difference between using a private directory offered by my host (1and1) vs just putting a .htaccess file in the directory to block users?

Comment: @kuuy - Surely you mean the command `Deny from all` in the `.htaccess` file. In practise this is also a good solution, theoretically the out-of-root directory is a bit more safe. The htaccess method relies on a correct configuration (are you working in a developer team?) and the assumption that the server software cannot be tricked somehow. Another advantage of the out-of-root directory is, that the password file is not part of version-control and permissions can be set restrictively for this directory.

Comment: So I have implemented the password_has() and password_verify() commands (it took some finagling of the 1and1 settings to switch the PHP version) and things are working perfectly. I also did indeed mean the Deny from all command!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd save them in a secure SQL database, or something of that description; hashing is supposed to be a second line of defence.

So if your database data gets breached and a hacker gets a hold of it, they won't be able to log on to everyone's account.

Usually the process with any type of Hash is that, once it's brought out, it would be the most secure it will ever be, and then gradually over time, with the collection of people and increased computer power, the hash will be "broken" usually through a collection of Rainbow tables, and will end up with a website such as [THIS](https://md5hashing.net/hash/sha256) which is what happened with Md5.

If you are going to store them in a .txt file, the minimum you can do on top of what you've already done, is to make sure you SALT the hashed password. 
Salting a hashed password decreases its chance of being cracked. Please refer to links below on how you would go about Salting your hash.

[Great video by Computerphile on YouTube about the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4b8ktEV4Bg)

[Good tutorial by CrackStation on how to Salt a Hash](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

[Good examples by W3Schools on Hashing/Salting](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_crypt.asp)

Comment: Nice mention of salt, make sure that you do it correctly with a random generated salt for each user.

Comment: Yeah forgot to add that.

Comment: I wouldn't consider anything by W3schools to be "good", especially when it comes to security. The crackstation article is great, although the author (Taylor Hornby) would probably point to [this page](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016) nowadays.

Comment: It's was more an example for beginners as oppose to 'copy this its standard procedure' sort of thing.